# sumproduct excel multiple tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, excel-2003

I have two tables and I want to count how many occurrences of an item by referencing another table,

for example, I want to know how many snakes Bob owns, the obvious answer is two but how do I do that in one formula? I have used sumproduct to calculate the number of occurrences of individual snakes but I want them all in one formula by referencing the second table. Is this possible?

**Note**:
I have excel 2003, hence sumproduct

```
    A      B    
1  Bob    Boa
2  Ann    Cow
3  Bob    Sheep
4  Bob    Python

    A      B
1  Farm   Snake
2  Cow    Boa
3  Sheep  Python
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear bob has two snakes, nor how the first table is related to the second. What are you expecting to do here?

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean that the items in column B on table 2 are names of snakes, and you want to count the number of snakes in the first table as are listed as snakes in the second table, that are owned by Bob? Can you use a helper column, or does this need to be one formula?

Comment: I would like to look up column B of the first table with the animal type "Snake" in the second table, if a match exists, include it in the count.

Comment: I can potentially use a helper column, however would rather not

Comment: Array formulas within array formulas don't really work well. A helper column is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do this with your existing layout and without helper columns. Assume first table in `A1:B4` and second table in `D1:E3` and you can get the number of snakes Bob owns with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A4="Bob")*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B4,INDEX(D2:E3,0, MATCH("snake",D1:E1,0)),0)))`

The first criterion is self-evident, I think.

For the second this part finds all the snake names:

`INDEX(D2:E3,0,MATCH("snake",D1:E1,0))`

....because it matches "snake" against the headers in D1:E1 and the returns the whole of the column below [by using zero as the row argument in INDEX you get the whole column].

Then, having all the snake names you can use MATCH to match B1:B4 against those. If there's a match you get a number, if not you get #N/A so you wrap the MATCH function in ISNUMBER to return TRUE/FALSE.

Another way is to use COUNTIF in place of ISNUMBER/MATCH

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A4="Bob")*(COUNTIF(INDEX(D2:E3,0, MATCH("snake",D1:E1,0)),B1:B4)>0))`

Comment: You guys are MVPs for a reason! +1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set up your lookup table properly. There is no way to lookup with your second table as it is. First change it as follows:

```
Farm  Cow
Farm  Sheep
Snake Boa
Snake Python
```

Now you can lookup what type of item the thing is by using this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

If you add that to column C in your original sheet, you will get this:

```
Bob Boa Snake
Ann Cow Farm
Bob Sheep   Farm
Bob Python  Snake
```

Then you can just use sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A4="Bob")*(C1:C4="Snake"))
```

Comment: You can't really use INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP with an array formula (which you would need to get something to use with SUMPRODUCT). You would need to use OFFSET to get the array instead: `=OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,MATCH(B1:B4,Sheet2!B:B,0)-1,0)` but that doesn't help because you can't use that array formula in a SUMPRODUCT (you get `#VALUE!` errors)

Comment: Yes this is the problem I was having